# JQuery recursive function in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, jquery, phonegap-build

I have been experimenting with PhoneGap and managed to create a basic memory game, which fades a sequence of numbers in and out, expecting the user to repeat it correctly. There's only the bare bones so you wont get any confirmation of a click until you finish the sequence.

The game can be accessed here: http://jdtremelling.com/mobile/index.html

And if you fancy it, for testing purposes, the app can be downloaded by scanning this QR code:
[image]

The problem is that only one number flashes in the sequence when the app loads and then nothing else happens. Its as if the recursive function never executes.

The code to initialise the JS array with lists of random numbers (increasing the sizes for each level) , then show the first sequence:

```
function initialiseArrays(){
                for(var i=4; i<9; i++){
                    var numbers = [];
                    for(var j=0; j<i; j++){
                        numbers.push(Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min) + min));
                    }
                    allNumbers.push(numbers.slice());
                }

                fadeThemOut(allNumbers[0]);
            }
```

The recursive JavaScript funciton:

```
    function fadeThemOut(children) {
var tmp = [];
   for(var i=0; i<children.length; i++){
      tmp[i] = children[i];
   }
   if (tmp.length > 0) {
      var currentChild = tmp.shift();
      switch(currentChild){
         case 1:
            $('#one').fadeOut('slow').delay( 800 ).fadeIn('slow', function() {
               fadeThemOut(tmp);
            });
            break;
         case 2:
             $('#two').fadeOut('slow').delay( 800 ).fadeIn('slow', function() {
                fadeThemOut(tmp);
             });
             break;
         case 3:
             $('#three').fadeOut('slow').delay( 800 ).fadeIn('slow', function() {
             fadeThemOut(tmp);
         });
         break;
       }
   }
}
```

Comment: Sorry! I was going to and then forgot. Hang on.

Comment: That QR code was not for advertising my app. That was so you can see it not working! Who would want to use a broken app?

Comment: if you are going to post that you need to format it so the QR code is smaller.

Comment: OK I can do that, but it can't be too small otherwise it wont scan. Also, why did you remove the link to the project?! That was the best way to explain the issue I am having. People can look at all the source they want there. Please leave it alone

Comment: I am not trying to destroy your question you just need to format it so people can help you. With the code added and the QR small it looks proper now. Thanks for fixing that. Good luck with your problem

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
fadeThemOut(allNumbers[0]);
```

to

```
fadeThemOut(allNumbers);
```

Comment: Thanks, but allNumbers is an array of arrays and I am just accessing the first entry to start the game off. Sorry, should have mentioned.